# Joomla Sub Menus not appearing

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, joomla, joomla3.0

I spent some time having problems with this so, thought I would share the solution.

Using Joomla's site menu creator, or other plugins to create menus, when I use parent items they do not drop down, or appear.

I have used Chrome's Inspect element to see if the link is there as well, but its not, so why?

Comment: which version ? Joomla 1.5 ? 1.6 ? 1.7 ? 2.5 ?

Comment: This was a 1.5 site but I've also seen it apply with 2.5

Comment: +1 for returning after two years to answer your own question. -1 for responding to comments after two years. Let's call it even. :)

Comment: @alfasin Sounds fair! I was having a clean up and thought "that questions getting lots of views, lets look at it", and your comment is relevant to anyone coming here.

Comment: not sure I'm with you about "anyone coming here" - when I post a question I make sure to respond to the commenters, after all - they invested their time in reading my question in purpose of helping me.

Comment: @alfasin Well yes this is very true - and normally I do reply to comments for just that reason - this one obviously slipped through though. Better late than never!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to fix, go to the Administrator home, click on Extensions > Module Manager > The correct menu module ( it will be there somewhere )

Then on the options screen for that module make sure the "Always show sub menu's" is selected to yes - note it is off by default!